# How to stop making tmux auto setting RBENV_VERSION

Tags: ruby, shell, tmux, rbenv

tmux is auto setting RBENV_VERSION when I start tmux...

Anyone know how to stop it?

Because it auto sets it, I need to do

`$ export RBENV_VERSION`

to unset it and make .ruby-version work. Thx.

Comment: oh maybe I figured out the reason. mabye tmux is auto setting. :O

Comment: edited title and body

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*tmux* itself will never set (or unset) RBENV_VERSION of its own accord. You have some bit of configuration that is causing this.

My guess is that RBENV_VERSION was set when you started your *tmux* server and that is is now part of the *tmux* “global environment” (the base environment inherited by all the processes started by *tmux*). You can check this

```
tmux show-environment -g | grep RBENV
```

If it is present there, you can delete it with this command:

```
tmux set-environment -gu RBENV_VERSION
```

If you often find yourself starting *tmux* when RBENV_VERSION is already set (and you do not want it sent “inside” *tmux*), then you can add the above command to your `~/.tmux.conf` file to make sure that it is cleared every time you start a server.

Another possibility is that it is part of your *tmux* “session environment”; this environment is “layered” atop the global environment to form the environment that is inherited by the processes started for new windows and panes in a session. You can check it with this command (run it inside the session, or add `-t sessname` to specify a session):

```
tmux show-environment | grep RBENV
```

If this is present, you can unset it in a similar way:

```
tmux set-environment -u RBENV_VERSION
```

Finally, if the variable is not present in either the global or session environments, then it is probably coming from something in your shell initialization files. By default, *tmux* starts login shells, so be sure to check the corresponding bits of shell configuration (e.g. `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile`, etc.) as well as any other bits of initialization.

Comment: Tried the first one and found out that RBENV_VERSION was set in global environment! THX!

Comment: This is great! I had the same issue as well and adding `set-environment -gu RBENV_VERSION` to the top of my ~/.tmux.conf solved it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To check if an environment variable is part of tmux's session environment, look at the output of

```
tmux show-environment
```

and then do the same for the global environment:

```
tmux show-environment -g
```

tmux starts login shells by default, so you could clear the global environment and let the login shells build it from scratch (from ~/.profile and so on).  Here is a way to do that:

```
(tmux show-environment -g |less |sed 's/=.*//' |while read e; do tmux set-environment -gu -- "$e"; done)
```